# Where should I place Google analytics code in my master page?

Tags: asp.net

Where should I place Google analytics code in my master page?

Comment: Whether it belongs before the </head> or </body> tag is discussed here: http://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/6438/google-analytics-changes-script-placement.aspx

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE (2018-10-22):**

Just after the `<head>` tag:

https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

Just before the `</head>` tag.

https://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1008080

Answer (score 2):

right before `</body>` tag to prevent slowing download js scripts from blocking page content.

More details: http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom

Comment: Guess maybe things have changes since '12 -- Google says in the `<head>` now. Also, that link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to put the Analytics snippet at the bottom of the page, you should know that you don't have to put the whole snippet at the bottom. You can still keep most of the benefits of asynchronous loading by splitting the snippet in half—keep the first half at the top of the page and move the rest to the bottom. Because the first part of the tracking snippet has little to no effect on page rendering, you can leave that part at the top and put the part of the snippet that inserts ga.js at the bottom.

A page with the asynchronous snippet split in half might look like this:

```
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var _gaq = _gaq || [];
    _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-X']);
    _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Page Content</p>

  <script src="some_random_script.js"></script>

  <p>Page Content</p>

  <script type="text/javascript">  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script');     ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:'   == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl'   : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Both pieces of code need to be wrapped in their own script tags, but only the last six lines of the original asynchronous snippet need to be moved to the bottom. All the lines that push methods onto _gaq can stay at the top.